Local file as absolute vs relative url: bad for performance or no difference?
If a local CSS file on a hosting is loaded in HEAD with an absolute URL, like https://example.com/style.css instead of relative /style.css, does it make a difference in terms of loading time?
More concretely asked: does an absolute URL here forces DNS resolving, SSL handshake and so on?

DNS lookups are cached for the given TTL, so the browser will not do a second DNS lookup if a resource is taken from the same domain. SSL handshake will not happen a second time if the server is well configured. This is done with the Keep-Alive configuration so that a connection to the server is not directly closed after each request. Browsers open several connections to the server, so they can download CSS, JS, images in parallel. Minify & compress (gzip, brotli) your assets.


does it make a difference in terms of loading time?

It adds an insignificant number of bytes to the source code.

does an absolute URL here forces DNS resolving, SSL handshake and so on?

No. A relative URL is resolves to an absolute URL, then the rest of the request happens the same.
